# Static Classes & Class design

Tags: c#, .net, static

While designing my data access layer, I wanted to make all my classes Static so that no object instantiation is required and all members of the class can be access using the class name.

Is this a good approach. If yes then why do we need to have a instance class type at all. Would it have an impact on the performance of the application where n clients want to access my DAL and then might cause a problem with managing the request(s) because no object is created at all?

I understand that static classes cannot be instantiated, and should be used for something like Logging, Utility methods etc, because all objects need to behave in a similar way, Is it valid/safe to assume that all DAL classes does behave the same way (have the same functionality) and hence make them static rather than instantiating it.

Please advice.

Comment: honestly, the only situation when I make use of static classes are abstract factories and extension method classes. Dont just make sonething static because it is used everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Either the type conceptually represents operations that are tied to instances, or it doesn't.  Performance is not a consideration here.

If your methods have no state, or their state is designed to be shared between all invocations of the method throughout the application, then the method should be static.  If there needs to be separate state shared between members but not shared with the entirety of the application then they need to be non-static.  The type will generally require one or the other based on what it conceptually represents.  It's not an *actual* choice.

Comment: I somewhat disagree - there are scenarious where you implement several 'service' objects that implement the same interface but do things differently. They do not have to have state in the form of fields. The main thing is that you cannot use polymorphism by using static method calls - the client would have to change, too.

Comment: +1. But see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25879270/467473). It is often useful to hide the static implementation from the users of the class.

Comment: @feO2x For polymorphism to make sense at all it requires, at a fundamental level, the idea of object instances.  It needs to make sense for instances of the type to be created, passed around, etc. to utilize the idea of having multiple instances of different types treated identically.  That would be a case where the core concept of the type you are creating is inherently representing a type of object, rather than an operation that is not connected to an object instance.  Since the type is conceptually tied to object instances, it should have non-static members.

Comment: @Servy: I agree with you. But in his question, Immortal (more or less) asked about the fundamental concept why to use object instances ("Is this a good approach. If yes then why do we need to have a instance class type at all."). Therefore I thought I should point him to the benefits of using objects instead of functions.

Answer (score 3):

Static classes are generally best avoided as they introduce tight coupling into your code.  They make unit testing much harder because the calls are "hard wired" and can't be easily stubbed out.

Much better would be to make them instances, but only instantiate a single instance.  If you couple this with dependency injection (i.e. passing the DAL object into the classes that need it) then you get looser coupling and can pass in a stub version for unit tests - look up Unity or Castle Windsor or other IoC frameworks to see how this works.

Answer (score 2):

There is an impact on performace - static method calls are faster than instance method calls, especially if you address late binding. But that's also the big advantage of object-oriented programming.

If you just use static classes and therefore static method calls, you do not have the ability to 'exchange objects' - and that is, in my opinion, the most important part of object-oriented programming. Have a look at the SOLID principles of Object-Oriented Design and you'll learn about the real benefits of this programming style. Of course this might come with a performance penalty, but usually you won't have to think about it, except if you want to program e.g. real-time applications. Correct usage of OOP and OOD makes your code extremely flexible and (somewhat) easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

A useful design pattern for this is a variation of a singleton. Set up your static implementatation, leaving the static methods `private`, exposing them via an object instance, like this:

```
class MySingletonClass
{
    //-----------------------------------------
    // here, we hide the static implementations
    //-----------------------------------------
    private static int privateFoo()
    {
        /* do something useful here */
    }
    private static string privateBar()
    {
        /* do something useful here */
    }

    //---------------------------------------
    // and expose them via an object instance
    //---------------------------------------
    public int Foo()
    {
        return privateFoo() ;
    }
    public string Bar()
    {
        return privateBar() ;
    }
}
```

Your static class now has the same semantics as an ordinary object instance. Static methods are invoked thus:

```
SomeStaticClass.SomeStaticMethod() ;
```

while non-static classes are references thus:

```
SomeNonStaticClass instance = new SomeNonStaticClass() ;
instance.SomeNonStaticMethod() ;
```

By exposing the [private] static methods via instance methods, you have **hidden the
implementation** from the object's users. Down the line, then, when you realize that
your static methods won't work any more (for whatever reason) and the class has to
become non-static, all you have to do is modify the internal implementation of the class.

If your class's users were directly referencing the static methods, you would have to change
every reference in your code base.

Comment: Whether a method is static or not is a representation of the conceptual operation being performed.  It's not just some implementation detail.  If you're changing a method's staticness then it's a sign that there was a core misunderstanding of what the operation represented from the start.  Designing code with the intent of changing it's core principles without causing breaking changes is going to be useful very, very rarely, because any time you actually get this wrong you almost certainly are going to have a *ton* of problems.  Your attempts to work around this issue will cause way more harm.